# Consolidate Excel Information in one e-mail for each user

Tags: excel, vba

My table is structured as:

```
Vendor              Consultor   CLIENT  Date        OS      Status
test@test.com       Andrew      NAME 1  25/12/2017  123456  Pend
test@test.com       Andrew      NAME 2  31/12/2017  789123  Pend
test134@test.com    Joseph      NAME 3  10/12/2017  654321  Pend
```

I need to consolidate everything that is pending for the seller "Andrew or Joseph" and send a single email with the "OS" list.
I am using the following code but unsuccessful as it opens a new email for each row of the worksheet:

```
Sub email()

Dim i As Long
Dim OutApp, OutMail As Object
Dim strto, strcc, strbcc, strsub, strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon

For i = 1 To Range("C5536").End(xlUp).Row
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strto = Cells(i, 1)
    strsub = "OS - PENDING"
    strbody = "Hello," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Please, check your pending OS's" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Detalhes:" & vbCrLf & _
        "Consultor:" & Cells(i, 3) & vbCrLf & _
        "Date:" & Cells(i, 4) & vbCrLf & _
        "OS:" & Cells(i, 5) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Best Regards" & vbCrLf & _
        "Team"

    With OutMail
        .To = strto
        .Subject = strsub
        .Body = strbody
        .Display

    End With
    On Error Resume Next

Next

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class cVendorline with the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private mClient As String
Private mDate As Date
Private mOS As String

Public Property Get Client() As String
        Client = mClient
End Property

Public Property Let Client(ByVal bNewValue As String)
        mClient = bNewValue
End Property        

Public Property Get dDate() As Date    
    dDate = mDate    
End Property

Public Property Let dDate(ByVal bNewValue As Date)    
    mDate = bNewValue    
End Property

Public Property Get OS() As String    
    OS = mOS    
End Property

Public Property Let OS(ByVal sNewValue As String)    
    mOS = sNewValue    
End Property
```

Then put the following code into a module and run Consolidate

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidate()

#If Early Then
    Dim emailInformation As New Scripting.Dictionary
#Else
    Dim emailInformation As Object
    Set emailInformation = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
#End If

    GetEmailInformation emailInformation
    SendInfoEmail emailInformation
End Sub

Sub GetEmailInformation(emailInformation As Object)

Dim rg As Range
Dim sngRow As Range

Dim emailAddress As String
Dim vendorLine As cVendorLine
Dim vendorLines As Collection

Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion    ' Assuming the list starts in A1 and DOES NOT contain empty row
Set rg = rg.Offset(1).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1)    ' Cut the headings

    For Each sngRow In rg.Rows

        emailAddress = sngRow.Cells(1, 1)

        Set vendorLine = New cVendorLine
        With vendorLine
            .Client = sngRow.Cells(1, 3)
            .dDate = sngRow.Cells(1, 4)
            .OS = sngRow.Cells(1, 5)
        End With

        If emailInformation.Exists(emailAddress) Then
            emailInformation.item(emailAddress).Add vendorLine
        Else
            Set vendorLines = New Collection
            vendorLines.Add vendorLine
            emailInformation.Add emailAddress, vendorLines
        End If

    Next

End Sub

Sub SendInfoEmail(emailInformation As Object)

Dim sBody As String
Dim sBodyStart As String
Dim sBodyInfo As String
Dim sBodyEnd As String
Dim emailAdress As Variant
Dim colLines As Collection
Dim line As Variant

    sBodyStart = "Hello," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                 "Please, check your pending OS's" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                 "Detalhes:" & vbCrLf

    For Each emailAdress In emailInformation
        Set colLines = emailInformation(emailAdress)
        sBodyInfo = ""

        For Each line In colLines
            sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & _
                    "Consultor:" & line.Client & vbCrLf & _
                    "Date:" & line.dDate & vbCrLf & _
                    "OS:" & line.OS & vbCrLf

        Next
        sBodyEnd = "Best Regards" & vbCrLf & _
                "Team"

        sBody = sBodyStart & sBodyInfo & sBodyEnd
        SendEmail emailAdress, "OS - PENDING", sBody
    Next


End Sub

Sub SendEmail(ByVal sTo As String _
              , ByVal sSubject As String _
                , ByVal sBody As String _
                  , Optional ByRef coll As Collection)


    #If Early Then
        Dim ol As Outlook.Application
        Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    #Else
        Dim ol As Object
        Dim outMail As Object
        Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    #End If

    Set outMail = ol.CreateItem(0)

    With outMail
        .To = sTo
        .Subject = sSubject
        .Body = sBody
        If Not (coll Is Nothing) Then
            Dim item As Variant
            For Each item In coll
                .Attachments.Add item
            Next
        End If

        .Display
        '.Send
    End With

    Set outMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @Storax! First of all, thanks for the help and your time!
I did what you said and I got an error " Compile Error".
The error is indicated in this line "Sub GetEmailInformation(emailInformation As Scripting.Dictionary)" apparently..

Comment: Sorry, I did not remove early binding in the whole code. It's done, I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: You have to add a new class with the name cVendorLine and put the code above into that class. Here is an example how to do that https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/#Creating_a_Simple_Class_Module

Comment: I Still cant run, the error is on "Sub GetEmailInformation(emailInformation As Object)" and Dim vendorLine As cVendorLine

Comment: It worked so good, Thanks! The only thing I'm concern is about the space between the "OS's" . Is it possible to add a row between?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can edit the mail message by editing the string sBodyInfo. Where do you need a space?

Comment: I could edit here.. sBodyInfo like you said! Thanks, you saved me a week of work.

Comment: May I ask you something?
Let's suppose each vendor has a supervisor and I will need to copy ( cc ). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, should be possible.

Comment: I'm trying to put the information somehow in the structure you've made.. so far no success. Can you help me?

Comment: I would suggst to open a new question with reference to this one and describe your problem at hand.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I did post now