# Excel VBA: Send automated dynamic emails

Tags: excel, vba

I know there are many questions & answers about this but I never found one that suited my needs and I am not sure how to do it (I am still learning).

I need to send automated emails when a button is pressed. I have a table that goes like this:

```
VID    VENDOR       CONTACT        CAUSE ID    CAUSE DESC       WK INCIDENCE     PLANNER
1224   FRUITY   LEIA@COMPANY.COM       1         No ETA         Between WK9-10    LEIA
1224   FRUITY   LEIA@COMPANY.COM       2         Wrong Format   Between WK9-10    LEIA
6554   BAGGS    LEIA@COMPANY.COM       2         Wrong Format   In WK9            LEIA
8455   GLASS    LINK@COMPANY.COM       3         Missing info   In WK10           LINK
```

What I need is a macro that will read the table above, get a unique list of recipients (planner) and send an email with all the info the table has available to the planner.

For example, for LEIA@COMPANY.COM, the email would go like this:

```
TO: LEIA@COMPANY.COM
CC: ""
BCC: ""
SUBJECT: "VEN CHECK [current week]: [unique list of vendors] 'Ex, FRUITY, BAGGS"
BODY: 
Hello [PLANNER], 'Ex. HEllo LEIA,

Your report was checked and the following results were found:
      1. [CAUSE DESC] in [DESC] 'Ex. No ETA in FRUITY
      2. [CAUSE DESC] in [DESC] 'Ex. Wrong Format in FRUITY
      3. [CAUSE DESC] in [DESC] 'Ex. Wrong Format IN BAGGS

Please, follow the standard protocol to fix this issues on time for next week check up.

Any questions, contact me.

Regards,
```

So far, I have the following:

```
Sub Send_Email()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim emailRng As Range
Dim recipient As Range
Dim contactList As String
Dim sTo() As String
Dim controlTable As ListObject

Set controlTable = Worksheets("Problems").ListObjects("TableProblem")

Set emailRng = controlTable.ListColumns("Contact").DataBodyRange

For Each recipient In emailRng
    If (recipient <> "") And (InStr(contactList, recipient) = 0) Then
        contactList = contactList & recipient & "|"
    End If
Next recipient

If Len(contactList) > 0 Then contactList = Left(contactList, Len(contactList) - 1)

sTo = Split(contactList, "|")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next

For i = LBound(sTo) To UBound(sTo)
    With OutMail
        .To = sTo(i)
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Body =
Next i
```

**PROBLEM:** My biggest problem is how to fix up the mail's body like the example above. It doesnt have to be exactly like that one, but the body should give the VENDOR, CAUSE DESC AND WK INCIDENCE.

I am not sure how to go on about this problem, maybe have a custom class? So far I have made simple classes with simple properties.

As you can see, I am stuck at creating the outlook item.

If you have the time and can help me, please do so.

Thanks,

Comment: Where's the part where you would add the body? What if you just built a string, perhaps using some line breaks?

Comment: Sounds good, better than my idea actually. But how am I going to build it?

Comment: What about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007366/consolidate-excel-information-in-one-e-mail-for-each-user/48008884#48008884

Comment: I don't know.  How's the data set up? I'd think just loop through the cells/range that would make up the body. Something like `For each cel in bodyRange // myBodyString = cel.Value & vbcrlf // next cel`?

Comment: Thanks Storax, that question worked well for me.