# How to send emails to unique users in range using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to look into the A column, find all unique email addresses, create an Outlook email for each and populate the body of that email with the rows where that email address is present (also including the header).

Example data:

```
+----------------+---------------------+---------+
|     Email      |     Application     | Version |
+----------------+---------------------+---------+
| test1@test.com | Microsoft_Office_13 | v2.0    |
| test1@test.com | Putty               | v3.0    |
| test1@test.com | Notepad             | v5.6    |
| test2@test.com | Microsoft_Office_13 | v2.0    |
| test2@test.com | Putty               | v3.0    |
| test2@test.com | Adobe_Reader        | v6.4    |
| test3@test.com | Microsoft_Office_13 | v3.6    |
| test3@test.com | Paint               | v6.4    |
| test3@test.com | Adobe_Reader        | v6.4    |
+----------------+---------------------+---------+
```

This is what I found, but it will create an email for every time the address is listed. It also doesn't have any code which shows how to pull a range of cells into the body.

```vb
Sub Test1()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Hi, please find your account permissions below:"
                .Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The desired email output would be something like:

Hi, please find your account permissions below:

```
+----------------+---------------------+---------+
|     Email      |     Application     | Version |
+----------------+---------------------+---------+
| test2@test.com | Microsoft_Office_13 | v2.0    |
| test2@test.com | Putty               | v3.0    |
| test2@test.com | Adobe_Reader        | v6.4    |
+----------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007366/consolidate-excel-information-in-one-e-mail-for-each-user/48008884#48008884) is of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007366/consolidate-excel-information-in-one-e-mail-for-each-user/48008884#48008884) mentioned in the comment and modified it.
Create a class and name it AppInfo. [Here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/#Creating_a_Simple_Class_Module) you find how to do that

```
Option Explicit

Public app As String
Public version As String
```

Then put the following code into a module. The asumption is that the data is in the active sheet starting in A1 with the header Email, Application and Version.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidate()

#If Early Then
    Dim emailInformation As New Scripting.Dictionary
#Else
    Dim emailInformation As Object
    Set emailInformation = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
#End If

    GetEmailInformation emailInformation
    SendInfoEmail emailInformation
End Sub


Sub GetEmailInformation(emailInformation As Object)

Dim rg As Range
Dim sngRow As Range

Dim emailAddress As String
Dim myAppInfo As AppInfo
Dim AppInfos As Collection

Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion    ' Assuming the list starts in A1 and DOES NOT contain empty row
Set rg = rg.Offset(1).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1)    ' Cut the headings

    For Each sngRow In rg.Rows

        emailAddress = sngRow.Cells(1, 1)

        Set myAppInfo = New AppInfo
        With myAppInfo
            .app = sngRow.Cells(1, 2)
            .version = sngRow.Cells(1, 3)
        End With

        If emailInformation.Exists(emailAddress) Then
            emailInformation.item(emailAddress).Add myAppInfo
        Else
            Set AppInfos = New Collection
            AppInfos.Add myAppInfo
            emailInformation.Add emailAddress, AppInfos
        End If

    Next

End Sub
Sub SendInfoEmail(emailInformation As Object)

Dim sBody As String
Dim sBodyStart As String
Dim sBodyInfo As String
Dim sBodyEnd As String
Dim emailAdress As Variant
Dim colLines As Collection
Dim line As Variant

    sBodyStart = "Hi, please find your account permissions below:" & vbCrLf


    For Each emailAdress In emailInformation
        Set colLines = emailInformation(emailAdress)
        sBodyInfo = ""
        For Each line In colLines
            sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & _
                         "Application: " & line.app & vbTab & "Version:" & line.version & vbCrLf
        Next
        sBodyEnd = "Best Regards" & vbCrLf & _
                   "Team"

        sBody = sBodyStart & sBodyInfo & sBodyEnd
        SendEmail emailAdress, "Permissions", sBody
    Next


End Sub

Sub SendEmail(ByVal sTo As String _
              , ByVal sSubject As String _
                , ByVal sBody As String _
                  , Optional ByRef coll As Collection)


    #If Early Then
        Dim ol As Outlook.Application
        Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    #Else
        Dim ol As Object
        Dim outMail As Object
        Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    #End If

    Set outMail = ol.CreateItem(0)

    With outMail
        .To = sTo
        .Subject = sSubject
        .Body = sBody
        If Not (coll Is Nothing) Then
            Dim item As Variant
            For Each item In coll
                .Attachments.Add item
            Next
        End If

        .Display
        '.Send
    End With

    Set outMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great!

Is it possible to insert their permissions as a table in the email?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Feel free to change the Sub SendEmail resp SendInfoMail accordingly.

Comment: Any idea how to pull the whole column? It seems that the code sets and then calls variables for each column, but I'm hoping to pull all the columns of all the rows which contain this email address in the column.

Comment: Yes but I think it's now a good time to try something on your own. If you get stuck post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in different ways, but I am just giving you a quick answer that will solve your problem. I used a function developed by Ron de Bruin to convert the range to an html body.

- I deleted one of the conditions to check the content of the cells in column A so make sure you put it back and test it with your own data
- I used a dictionary to store the emails we generate the outlook instance so if in the other cells you have the same email you would not generate the email again
- you need to use an html body instead of body in the outlook new item so that you have more options to quickly paste your content and format it (color, size, font etc)

  ```
  Option Explicit


  Sub Test1()
      Dim OutApp As Object
      Dim OutMail As Object
      Dim dict As Object 'keep the unique list of emails
      Dim cell As Range
      Dim cell2 As Range
      Dim rng As Range
      Dim i As Long
      Dim WS As Worksheet

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
      Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change the name of the sheet accordingly

      On Error GoTo cleanup
      For Each cell In WS.Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
          If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

              'check if this email address has been used to generate an outlook email or not
              If dict.exists(cell.Value) = False Then

                  dict.Add cell.Value, "" 'add the new email address
                  Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                  Set rng = WS.UsedRange.Rows(1)

                  'find all of the rows with the same email and add it to the range
                  For Each cell2 In WS.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
                      If cell2.Value = cell.Value Then
                          Set rng = Application.Union(rng, WS.UsedRange.Rows(cell2.Row))
                      End If
                  Next cell2

                  On Error Resume Next
                  With OutMail
                      .To = cell.Value
                      .Subject = "Reminder"
                      .HTMLBody = "Hi, please find your account permissions below:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & RangetoHTML(rng)
                      .Display
                  End With

                  On Error GoTo 0
                  Set OutMail = Nothing
              End If
          End If
      Next cell

  cleanup:
      Set OutApp = Nothing
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub

  Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
  ' coded by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
  ' Working in Office 2000-2016
      Dim fso As Object
      Dim ts As Object
      Dim TempFile As String
      Dim TempWB As Workbook

      TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

      'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
      rng.Copy
      Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
      With TempWB.Sheets(1)
          .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
          .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
          .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
          .Cells(1).Select
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
          On Error Resume Next
          .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
          .DrawingObjects.Delete
          On Error GoTo 0
      End With

      'Publish the sheet to a htm file
      With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
           SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
           Filename:=TempFile, _
           Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
           Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
           HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
          .Publish (True)
      End With

      'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
      RangetoHTML = ts.readall
      ts.Close
      RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                            "align=left x:publishsource=")

      'Close TempWB
      TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

      'Delete the htm file we used in this function
      Kill TempFile

      Set ts = Nothing
      Set fso = Nothing
      Set TempWB = Nothing
  End Function
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, in my opinion, would be to format your table as a table in Excel (which will enable search and sort). Then you could do something like e.g.

```
email = "test1@test.com"
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=email
Set data = tbl.DataBodyRange
If (data.Rows.Count = 0) Then Exit Sub
```

If execution makes it past the check (data.Rows.Count > 0) then you can send a mailer using HTML:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
bodyText = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
            " Hi, please find your account permissions below: <br> </BODY> "
With mail
    .To = email
    .Subject = "Email title here."
    .HTMLBody = bodyText & "<p>" & RangeToHTML(data)
    .Importance = 1 ' normal
    .Display
End With
```

which requires the following helper function:

```
Function RangeToHTML(rng As Range) As String

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim tempFile As String
Dim tempWB As Workbook

    tempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set tempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With tempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With tempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=tempFile, _
         Sheet:=tempWB.Sheets(1).name, _
         Source:=tempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Offset(1).Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(tempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangeToHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangeToHTML = Replace(RangeToHTML, _
                    "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")

    tempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    Kill tempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set tempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

You can modify as needed.