# Filter on To address and send email to one person with two or more rows in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

From the table below I want to:

1-Filter per column B for unique values.
2-Once filtered if its only "1" row, then put each cell on that row into a variable.
3-Once filtered if the result is more than 1 record, meaning the same email address has two or more records then grab all the range from A to E (range to HTML).
4-Paste the information in an email.
5-Loop until column B hits a blank cell, which means its the end.

```
Table Example:  
Record ID   Email   Data    Data    Data
Record1 test1@test.com  1   1   1
Record2 test2@test.com  2   2   2
Record3 test1@test.com  3   3   3
```

The following emails should be sent or displayed:
1- One email with two rows with all columns from A to E to test1@test.com in a range to Html.
2- One email with one row with all columns from A to E to test2@test.com in variable then paste them into HTML.

```vb
'*** You must have a Outlook email configured in outlook application on your system ***
'*** add reference to outook object library from references in tools ***

Sub BulkMail()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim WB As String
    Dim WB1 As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Path As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim ALastRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
    WB = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")

    WB1 = "CCE Allocation Email Source\Email Source file.xlsx"
    
        Path = WB & "\" & WB1
     
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path
    

'Creating references to Application and MailItem Objects of Outlook
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem

'Creating variable to hold values of different items of mail
Dim sendTo, subj, atchmnt, msg, ccTo, bccTo As String
Dim name As String

Dim lstRow As Long

'My data is on sheet "Exceltip.com" you can have any sheet name.
 Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With WS
'Getting last row of containing email id in column 3.
lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
'Variable to hold all email ids

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:H" & lstRow)

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("H2:H" & lstRow)


'initializing outlook object to access its features
Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
'On Error GoTo cleanup 'to handle any error during creation of object.

'Loop to iterate through each row, hold data in of email in variables and send
'mail to each email id.

For Each cell In rng1
    sendTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2
    name = Split(cell, ".")(0)
    strHtml = "<html>" & "<body>" & "Hi " & name & ", <br><br> Here is the information to report your time in PSA for the week of March 21 to March 25, 2022" & "<br>" & "</br>" & "</body>" & "</html>"
    strHtml1 = "<html>" & "<body>" & "<font face='Arial'> <p style=font-size:10pt>" & "<br><br><b>Thanks & Regards</font><br><br> " & " <font face='Cambria' color='blue'> <style=font-size:11pt><i>Padmini Chandrashekar</i></b><br></font>" & _
 "<font face='Arial'><style=font-size:10pt><b>PCO,CMU</b></font><br><font face='Calibri' color='blue'><font style=font-size:10pt>ITIL-V4 Foundation Certified<br></font></font><font face='Arial'><font style=font-size:8pt>India Global Delivery Center|<font color='red'>CGI</font><br>E-City Tower II , Electronic City Phase 1,<br>Bangalore, India - 560100.<br>|<font color='blue'>M-9739012740</font>|</font><br><br><font color='red'><b>Vacation Alert : Nil</b></font></p>" & "</body>" & "</html>"

    On Error Resume Next 'to hand any error during creation of below object
    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'Writing and sending mail in new mail
    With outMail
        .To = sendTo
        .cc = ""
        .Subject = "PSA for the week of March 18 to March 21"
        .HTMLBody = strHtml & RangetoHTML(Union(rng.Rows(1), Application.Intersect(rng, cell.EntireRow))) & strHtml1
        
        '.Attachments.Add atchmnt
        '.Send 'this send mail without any notification. If you want see mail
         .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0 'To clean any error captured earlier
    Set outMail = Nothing 'nullifying outmail object for next mail
 Next cell 'loop ends

cleanup: 'freeing all objects created
        Set outApp = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send emails to unique users in range using Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140980/how-to-send-emails-to-unique-users-in-range-using-excel-vba)

Comment: Hi , i have used the code below: but it is giving me both the rows which one person, i am trying to use the second solution which is given ; **With OutMail
                    .To = cell.Value
                    .Subject = "Reminder"
                    .HTMLBody = "Hi, please find your account permissions below:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & RangetoHTML(Union(rng.Rows(1), Application.Intersect(rng, cell.EntireRow)))
                    .Display
                End With**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique email addresses are saved to a dictionary.

Data is filtered once for each dictionary entry then visible data is passed to `RangetoHTML`.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant


Sub BulkMail()

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wBPathRoot As String
    Dim wB1 As String
    Dim Path As String
    
    Dim wbDataSource As Workbook
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim emailAddress As String
    
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim arrKey As Variant
    
    ' To store unique email addresses
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    wBPathRoot = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
    Debug.Print wBPathRoot
    
    WB1 = "CCE Allocation Email Source\Email Source file.xlsx"
    
    Path = wBPathRoot & "\" & wB1
    Debug.Print Path
    
    Set wbDataSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path)
    
    ' Early binding requires reference to Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library
    ' Application and MailItem Objects of Outlook
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    ' Variables to hold values of different items of mail
    Dim sendTo As String
    Dim subj As String
    Dim strHtml As String
    
    Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
    
    Set wS = wbDataSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    With wS
    
        'Getting last row containing emailAddress in column 2.
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Debug.Print "LastRow: " & LastRow
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            Debug.Print "B" & i
            emailAddress = .Range("B" & i)
            Debug.Print " emailAddress: " & emailAddress
            
            If Not objDictionary.Exists(emailAddress) Then
                objDictionary.Add emailAddress, True
                Debug.Print " Added: " & emailAddress
            End If
        Next
        
    End With
    
    arrKey = objDictionary.Keys
        
    'For i = LBound(arrKey) To UBound(arrKey)
    '    Debug.Print " Key " & i & " - " & arrKey(i)
    'Next
    
    For i = LBound(arrKey) To UBound(arrKey)
    
        Debug.Print " Key " & i & " - " & arrKey(i)
        emailAddress = arrKey(i)
        
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
        With wS
            
            wS.Range("A1:E" & LastRow).AutoFilter 2, "=" & emailAddress
            
            Dim visRange As Range
            Set visRange = wS.Range("A1:E" & LastRow).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
            sendTo = emailAddress
            
            'Writing and sending new mail
            With OutMail
                .To = sendTo
                .Subject = "PSA for the week of March 18 to March 21"
                strHtml = "<html>" & "<body>" & "Hi " & "</body>"
                .HTMLBody = strHtml & RangetoHTML(visRange)
                .Display
            End With
            
            Set OutMail = Nothing 'nullifying OutMail object for next mail
            
         End With
        
     Next
     
cleanup:
    'freeing objects created
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    If wS.AutoFilterMode Then wS.ShowAllData
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Debug.Print "Done"
    
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Niton , sorry for late reply , but i tried the above code , my email address column is at the last "G" so i have changed the column accordingly but it is not giving me the data in the table , auto filter could be the issue: With wS
            
            wS.Range("A1:G" & LastRow).AutoFilter 2, "=" & emailAddress

Comment: Hi Niton, It has worked now but i need name as well in the body , in my previous code i have added like this , For Each cell In rng1
    sendTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2
    name = Split(cell, ".")(0)
    strTextProperCase = StrConv(name, vbProperCase) but can you suggest me where can i add this in the new code

Comment: Looks like you want to manipulate the raw data. You could post a question about adding a column. Once you finalize the data, adjust the columns specified in the filter.

Comment: okay , i will try and confirm if it's working