# Limiting email to a single send in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, email, send

I would like to send three emails at the same time, but with different content each, and to different recipients.

The condition of sending emails out is by checking column N and column O are filled. Only rows which the cells under these two columns will be included in the table for the emails.

My problem is, when I only fill one rows, the email is sent once for each email. But when I fill two rows, the emails are sent twice, so it become a total of 6 emails with same content sent out.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
Sub SendEmails()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Dim sqlConnection As Object
    Dim sqlCommand As Object
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    Dim sqlResult As Object
    Dim recipientEmail As String
    
    ' Set the workbook and worksheet where the data is located
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("View Result & Commodity Change")
    
    ' Set the range of data to be processed (assuming data starts from row 3)
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A3:O" & lastRow)
    
    ' Create Outlook Application object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Create SQL Connection object
    Set sqlConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    ' Set the connection string to your SQL server
    ' Replace "server", "database", "username", and "password" with your actual values
    sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "myConnection;"
    
    ' Open the SQL Connection
    sqlConnection.Open
    
    ' Loop through each row in the range
    For Each row In rng.Rows
        ' Check if the cells in columns N and O are filled
        If Not IsEmpty(row.Cells(1, "N").Value) And Not IsEmpty(row.Cells(1, "O").Value) Then
            ' Compose the email subject and body
            EmailSubject = "Test: Application"
            emailBody = "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>" & "Dear User," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>"
            emailBody = emailBody & "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>" & "The data will be updated in database soon. Kindly wait for approval." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>"
            emailBody = emailBody & GetTableFromSQL(sqlConnection)
            emailBody = emailBody & "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>" & "Thank you and best regards." & vbCrLf & "<br/><i>" & "This is auto generate email and please do not reply the email." & vbCrLf & "</i><p>"
            
            ' Create a new Outlook mail item
            Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
            
            ' Set the email properties
            With outlookMail
                .Subject = EmailSubject
                .HTMLBody = emailBody
                .To = GetUsersOutlookEmail
                .CC = "member1@non.company.com;member2@company.com"
                .Display ' Use .Send to send the email without displaying
                .Send
            End With
            
            ' Search for the corresponding email in the SQL table based on the value in column L
            sqlQuery = "SELECT Email FROM tablename WHERE column_A = '" & row.Cells(1, "L").Value & "'"
            Set sqlCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
            With sqlCommand
                .ActiveConnection = sqlConnection
                .CommandText = sqlQuery
                Set sqlResult = .Execute
            End With
            
            ' Check if a matching email was found
            If Not sqlResult.EOF Then
                recipientEmail = sqlResult.Fields("Email").Value
                
                ' Compose the email subject and body
                EmailSubject = "Test: Application"
                emailBody = "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>" & "Dear Manager," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>"
                emailBody = emailBody & "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>" & "The table below is the proposed changes." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>"
                emailBody = emailBody & GenerateTable(rng)
                emailBody = emailBody & "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>" & "Thank you and best regards." & vbCrLf & "<br/><i>" & "This is auto generate email and please do not reply the email." & vbCrLf & "</i><p>"
                
                ' Create a new Outlook mail item
                Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
                
                ' Set the email properties
                With outlookMail
                    .Subject = EmailSubject
                    .HTMLBody = emailBody
                    .To = recipientEmail
'                    .Display ' Use .Send to send the email without displaying
                    .Send
                End With
            End If
            
            ' Search for the corresponding email in the SQL table based on the value in column N
            sqlQuery = "SELECT Email FROM tablename WHERE column_A = '" & row.Cells(1, "N").Value & "'"
            Set sqlCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
            With sqlCommand
                .ActiveConnection = sqlConnection
                .CommandText = sqlQuery
                Set sqlResult = .Execute
            End With
            
            ' Check if a matching email was found
            If Not sqlResult.EOF Then
                recipientEmail = sqlResult.Fields("Email").Value
                
                ' Compose the email subject and body
                EmailSubject = "Test: Application For Commoditization Tool"
                emailBody = "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>" & "Dear Manager," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>"
                emailBody = emailBody & "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>" & "The table below is the proposed changes." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<p>"
                emailBody = emailBody & GenerateTable(rng)
                emailBody = emailBody & "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>" & "Thank you and best regards." & vbCrLf & "<br/><i>" & "This is auto generate email and please do not reply the email." & vbCrLf & "</i><p>"
                
                ' Create a new Outlook mail item
                Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
                
                ' Set the email properties
                With outlookMail
                    .Subject = EmailSubject
                    .HTMLBody = emailBody
                    .To = recipientEmail
'                    .Display ' Use .Send to send the email without displaying
                    .Send
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next row
    
    ' Close the SQL connection
    sqlConnection.Close
    
    ' Release the objects
    Set sqlResult = Nothing
    Set sqlCommand = Nothing
    Set sqlConnection = Nothing
    Set outlookMail = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    
Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if understand exactly what you want: You want to send these 3 emails if **at least** one row satisfies the conditions. If so, then add the line `Exit For` just before the last `End If` (i.e. after sending the 3rd email)

Comment: A dictionary of unique email addresses may be appropriate https://stackoverflow.com/a/51142015/1571407 `If dict.exists(cell.Value) = False Then`